# Help with using schtasks, defining a specific time

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have successfully created a task, although I am having trouble defining when it should occur e.g. using the /MO command.

How is it possible to tell schtasks to execute this on e.g. every 5 days on the 4th hour of that day?

```
schtasks.exe /Create /SC DAILY /TN "testing123" /TR "C:\Program Files\test\scanner.exe 'C:\'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
/SC DAILY /MO 5 /ST 04:00
```